# Selenium Webdriver angular.js button

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have the code which I am trying to run in Selenium webdriver. It is a button but I can't select it with java code. Can you please help me which is true ?

```css
<mat-list-item _ngcontent-c7="" class="menu-item mat-list-item ng-star-inserted" id="kisiler"><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div>
          <!----><mat-icon _ngcontent-c7="" class="mat-icon material-icons ng-star-inserted" role="img" aria-hidden="true">group</mat-icon>
          <!---->
          <!----><mat-label _ngcontent-c7="" class="ng-star-inserted">Kişiler</mat-label>
        </div></mat-list-item>
```

My code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("[@id='kisiler']")).click();
```

Comment: correct your code `driver.findElement(By.id("kisiler")).click();`

Comment: it doesnt work @NarendraR , and the exception is  
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <mat-list-item id="kisiler" class="menu-item mat-list-item ng-star-inserted"> is not clickable at point (94.5,144) because another element <div class="apsi-container"> obscures it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Kisiler** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//mat-list-item[@class='menu-item mat-list-item ng-star-inserted' and @id='kisiler']//mat-label[@class='ng-star-inserted']"))).click();
  ```